# Tomcat Server & Geoserver working under one profile but another

Tags: geoserver, tomcat, profile

I am a really beginner with tomcat and geoserver and this is my first attempt at these programs.

I am having a problem getting geoserver to run under a different profile on my local machine.  I am running Tomcat 7.0.55 on a windows 7 system.  I installed tomcat and geoserver under the administrator profile and both work.  Now I want to get this working under my own profile and when I switched profiles I get the following error:

HTTP Status 404 - /geoserver/

type Status report

message /geoserver/

description The requested resource is not available.

When I hit start on the tomcat I get this error:

> FAIL - Application at context path /geoserver could not be started

Comment: Does tomcat work (ignoring the geoserver part)?

Comment: Yes the tomcat works

Answer (score 1):

Ciao,
this should be related to filesystem permissions that are missing for the non-admin user.

Make sure the current user has RW access rights to the GeoServer data directory whose location can be found by opening the status page of GeoServer itself.

Hope that helps,
Simone.

Comment: I found where you were talking but I can't figure out how to give permission to another user.  Data directory just points to a file location and I can't edit it (nor would I know what to edit it to be)

Comment: This link from the GeoServer doc gives more information: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/datadirectory/data-dir-setting.html. 

You just need to check windows docs for changing the permissions on the data directory and its subfolders. As an instance I found this guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx